# Android: It is possible to change the view programmaticaly

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext

Is it possible to change the view appearance order programmaticaly?

Example.

```
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_txt_address_location_street"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="8"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_edit_text"
                    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_txt_address_location_street_nr"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_edit_text"
                    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />
```

The xml about show the normal appearance order.

```
1. edit_txt_address_location_street
2. edit_txt_address_location_street_nr
```

For some conditions i muss invert the appearance order programmaticaly. 
E.g.:

```
1. edit_txt_address_location_street_nr
2. edit_txt_address_location_street
```

Comment: please explain your question.

Comment: You may try to [removeView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeView(android.view.View)) then [addView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View)) of the same EditText. For example _removeView(locationStreetEditText)_ then _addView(locationStreetEditText)_

Comment: @Basbous i just update my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most, if not all, of the xml commands have their corresponding programmatic calls. Assuming what you mean "change" is adding or removing a view after it is inflated with xml, then the answer is yes, but it is does not mean you should.

If you want to add/remove views dynamically , you would probably just better off creating the whole layout dynamically. Trust me it is not that hard compared to xml layout once you know how. I've read some where that there could be potentially some problems if you mix both xml and dynamic layout, I can't prove that statement, but what I have done is to inflate an empty linearlayout with xml, then dynamically add all the views I want.

Answer (score 2):

```
EditText location_street = new EditText(this);
location_street.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_edit_text);

EditText location_street_nr = new EditText(this);
location_street_nr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_edit_text);

LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.textlayout);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
ll.addView(location_street, lp);
ll.addView(location_street_nr, lp);
```